# Cannot connect SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services and Database on separate server

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, remote-server

I have two virtual machines runs on my laptop, let's say their name are VMApp and VMDB, and both are runs the same OS, Windows Server 2008 R2.

On VMDB, I installed all SQL Server 2008 features except the Reporting Services. in contrast, I installed only SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services on VMApp.

I run Reporting Services Configuration Manager on VMApp and point the Server Name to the VMDB's computer name, then I got an error message

```
"A connection to the computer cannot be established"
```

I enabled the named pipe from SQL Server Configuration Tools on VMDB, but I still get that error message on VMApp.

I think the problem is not network connection because the VMs are connected in same domain network and they could ping each other.

Sorry for this dumb case because I am newbie in SQL Server, and I really appreciate any help from you guys!

Regards,
Chrisma Andhika

Comment: Is the SQL server a named instance on the VMDB?

Comment: Yes matthew, it is a named instance.

Comment: Ok. So just to cover the basics do you have TCP/IP enabled (the are essential remote machines to each other) and you are connecting to the server such that SERVERNAME\INSTANCENAME?

Comment: I enabled the TCP/IP on SQL Server Configuration Tool on VMDB but I cannot find the option on VMApp because I only install Reporting Services on VMApp.

Comment: Are you pointing the VMApp to VMDB\INSTANCE_NAME OR just VMDB?

Answer (score 1):

You cant set the DB path to SERVERNAME\INSTANCENAME on the configuration manager. There isnt even that option. First you set the server:

[image]

and then the DB:
[image]

where exactly are you having your issue?

FYI: try to enable SQL Browser on VMDB or to connect by IP if you cant enable browser